# width of copy inside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I find the width of an element in JavaScript/jQuery without counting the part that is trailing whitespace.  The result for the example below would be 16px because it is only one character, and the font size is 16px.

```
<div class="styled" 
     style="width: 1024px; margin: 5px; border: 100px solid lemonchiffon;">
0
​</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#whateverYourDivIs").children().width()` ?

Since you want to get at only the text, get the computed width of the text node inside the div

Comment: $(".styled").children() will be an empty array.

Comment: You are referring to $(".styled")[0].childNodes[0].  This however is a string.  It is not possible to ascertain the needed information from this object.

Comment: `$("#theDiv").wrapInner("<span></span>").children().width()` works for my simple example. It gets the width of the inline span which is the exact length of the text (assuming no css is applied to the span). This is probably pretty slow and hackish though. It also makes it hard to get the span back out since there's no unWrapInner()